# Acceder a datos externos Java

Tags: java

tengo poca experiencia en programación, quería saber cuál es la forma más "limpia" de hacer lo siguiente en Java:

Estoy haciendo un programa que, entre otras cosas, al ejecutarse, deberá leer un archivo de información en concreto dependiendo del parámetro que se le pase. 
En este archivo, habrá datos estadísticos sobre este parámetro, quizás unos 20 datos sobre él, y cada parámetro se correspondería con un único archivo.

Mi duda es cuál es la mejor forma de guardar esta información, teniendo en cuenta que el número de parámetros es muy bajo (no más de 20) por lo que preferiría evitar una base de datos.
También sería preferible que fuera legible desde fuera del programa, no simplemente serializar objetos, de manera que hubiera la posibilidad de modificar uno de estos archivos directamente abriendo el archivo con un editor de texto. (Quizá un XML?)

Por último, una solución rápida que me podría servir sería inicializar unos objetos estáticos en el propio código, sería una solución muy horrible?

Gracias.

EDITO: El tiempo de lectura no es relevante porque sólo se accederá una vez durante la ejecución, y esta posiblemente dure varios minutos

Comment: Sí, creo que los más lógico sería usar XML o JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos maneras posibles, para ti que estas empezando, me miraría el `FileOutputStream / FileInputStream` o el `RandomAccesFile`. Como he visto que queires crear objetos para guardarlos en un fichero, te recomiendo el Stream. Si necesitas ayuda te puedo pasar un ejemplo comentado y muy fácil de visualizar de como tratarlo.

Te recomiendo que lo hagas mediante objetos así podrás ver como funciona el POO de Java. Además, trata de hacer un diseño descendiente bien diseñado.